# Win11 problem: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module

Tags: python, pandas, visual-c++, pip, pycharm

I use pip to install a python pakage pandas. When I begin the install with`pip install pandas`, I get this erro message. It look like a bit difference bettwen the sample MSVC version problem. I have reinstall the vitrual studio with it's MSCV but this erro message still display. I find the problem from another pakage called `nes-py`. When I use pip to install it the terminal give a same erro message.

My computer eviroment is Win11 + VS. I also install mingw from the msys2. I find same question have been aked when someone use mingw so I suppose that the problem is pip choose an erro complier. Can anyone solve this problem.

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\fanby\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x9gin6nr\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
      raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
  distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
```

Comment: The are two posts with this error message, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74802104) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76001458). In the 1st post the user solved the problem by creating a clean venv and isolating it from the site-packages, in the second case there's a comment suggests there's a conflict with installed libraries and removing the packages causing the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [msys2/mingw64: pip: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166914/msys2-mingw64-pip-vc-6-0-is-not-supported-by-this-module)