# Pydroid3 installing jupyter fails because of missing rust

Tags: python, mobile, pydroid

I wanted to code on jupyter notebook on my samsung tab. Therefore i installed pydroid3 and tried to install the jupyter by : pip install jupyter
But this did not work, because of an error which said, that rust could not be found (1). I then tried to install rust with https://rustup.rs/ but there came an error that the TLS algnement was 16 and needed to be 64 (2).
[1: error code after trying to install jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dihy5.jpg)
[2: error code after trying to install rust via link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdTDf.jpg)

First i tried to update pip to the newest version which worked and then tried to install jupyter again, but that failed.
Then I tried to install rust, but that failed because of the TLS alignement issue.

Thank you for your answers!

Here is the code after trying to install rust with pip:

````
sh: pkg: not found
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files $ pip install rust
Requirement already satisfied: rust in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pysam in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from rust) (0.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from rust) (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from rust) (1.21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->rust) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->rust) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->rust) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->rust) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->rust) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib->rust) (1.16.0)
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files $```

And here is the error code after i tried pip install jupyter:

``` /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files $ pip install jupyter
  
            writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            running build_ext
            running build_rust
            error: can't find Rust compiler

            If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

            To update pip, run:

                pip install --upgrade pip

            and then retry package installation.

            If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
      Failed to build maturin
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files $```

Then I tried to use the link to install rust, but an alignement error occured:

```/ $ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
info: downloading installer
Warning: Not enforcing strong cipher suites for TLS, this is potentially less secure
error: "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/tmp.35PK8APSgy/rustup-init": executable's TLS segment is underaligned: alignment is 16, needs to be at least 64 for ARM64 Bionic
Aborted ```
````

Comment: maybe you can do `pkg install rust` to install rust tooling ?

Comment: Can you add the error log, in question Please avoid using Images for error logs.

Comment: Yes, i already tried to install rust, though pkg did not work, so i used pip install rust.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`pip install\` Gives Error on Some Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73378545/pip-install-gives-error-on-some-packages)